# R: Using decompose() in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, aggregate

Hi I have a time series data as follows:

```
Code    Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1001    2009    183 175 151 173 169 169 158 132 91  91  146 114
1001    2010    76  103 130 103 78  72  64  96  89  91  61  62
1001    2011    73  50  99  90  74  112 113 111 112 112 97  137
1001    2012    105 140 160 129 162 161 150 167 151 161 114 120
1001    2013    140 137 153 128 137 137 135 148 116 134 121 95
1001    2014    135 145 144 110 109 130 110 58  100 109 67  66
1015    2009    21  19  19  21  17  29  56  35  46  33  42  45
1015    2010    46  29  55  62  49  48  44  37  39  46  33  39
1015    2011    59  36  52  41  36  38  42  43  37  37  37  35
1015    2012    46  53  55  41  69  41  38  42  37  50  46  48
1015    2013    64  43  58  43  50  39  29  48  45  26  51  55
1015    2014    40  54  64  58  76  59  69  66  57  60  58  55
1031    2009    2408    2370    2799    3460    3263    3102    2769    2749    3018    3283    3343    3193
1031    2010    3130    3069    3776    3348    3341    4129    3920    4131    4152    4044    4241    3522
1031    2011    3454    3768    5217    4242    4624    5105    4712    6064    5546    6049    5957    4670
1031    2012    4959    3554    2163    1274    1452    1248    1303    1278    916 906 522 324
1031    2013    537 442 417 389 469 423 328 246 291 387 201 122
1031    2014    249 203 42  30  29  36  39  16  36  23  11  19
```

I am trying to find the decomposition of the timeseries by Code column as different Codes have different trends and seasonality during various months.

I tried using data.table but it gives me error. Following is the code that I am using:

```
sa_data_ssn_cnt_ts <- data.table(sa_data_ssn_cnt_ts)

sa_data_ssn_cnt_si <- sa_data_ssn_cnt_ts[,list(SI = decompose(sa_data_ssn_cnt_ts, type = "multiplicative", filter = NULL)), by = sa_data_ssn_cnt_ts$site_id]
```

Error that I get:

```
Error in decompose(sa_data_ssn_cnt_ts, type = "multiplicative", filter = NULL) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

What is it that I am messing up here?

Is there any other way that I can get the decompositions by Code column?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with R's time series class, but the syntax you want is liable to look more like `DT[, decompose(.SD, type = "multiplicative", filter=NULL), by=Code]`. Maybe you should show how you would use `decompose` on a data.frame (say, with just a single code) to help us understand the problem.